# F# observable filter with side effect

Tags: f#, observable, frp

I have a number of events that are merged into one observable that executes some commands. If a command succeeded some result takes place. In addition, the command should be logged.

In terms of code, this looks like

```
    let mevts = modifyingevents |> Observable.filter exec_action
                    |> Observable.add (fun action -> self.OutlineEdited <- true)
```

where the function `exec_action` results in some side effect such as editing a treeview. If this succeeded then the property `OutlineEdited` is set to `true`.

I was hoping to follow this with something like

```
    mevts |> Observable.scan (fun log action -> action::log) []
```

but it turns out that [Observable.filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370380.aspx) is executed once for *each subscribed observer*. Meaning that the side effect will be repeated.

Can you please suggest another way to achieve the same result without having the `exec_action` executed twice? I am hoping to avoid having to use a mutable variable if possible.

Comment: You could have `exec_action` operate on a `lazy` internally, so that evaluation only occurs on the first execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example ilustrates nicely the difference between the `IObservable<'T>` type (used in this example via the `Observable` module) and the F# type `IEvent<'T>` (and functions in `Event` module).

When you use *observables*, every subscriber creates a new chain of operations (so side-effects are executed once for every subscriber). If you use *events* then the state is shared and side-effects are executed just once (regardless of the number of subscribers). On the other hand, the events do not get garbage collected when you remove all subscribers from an *event*.

So, if you do not need the events to be removed when all subscribers are removed, you should get the behaviour you want just by using `Event` instead of `Observable`:

```
modifyingevents 
|> Event.filter exec_action 
|> Event.scan (fun log action -> action::log) []
```

Comment: Working perfectly! I guess that begs the question: what if I wanted the garbage collection with the shared state. I have no need for that now, so I guess I will leave it to another day.