# f# observable fork and side effect

Tags: f#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an observable chain, the initial observable is from network, and will be fired every time message is ready to be read. The next handler then read the message and deserialize it. Now I have a fork of the observable, one is message handler and the other is logging the message.

The problem is that because I'm using observable I will actually try to read the message twice.

I understand that using Event instead of Observable will solve the issue, however I will then have a garbage collection issue that might cause sockets to not being collected.

One solution I thought of is to insert some kind of separator which end one chain of observables and creates a new one, does such a function already exist as part of fsharp or other library library.

Are there other solutions to the problem?

Edit:

Code example that doesn't work correctly

```
let messagesStream = 
  socket.observable |>
  Observable.map (fun () -> socket.read ()) |>
  Observable.map (fun m -> deserialize m)

messagesStream |> Observable.add (fun m -> printf m)
messagesStream |> Observable.add (fun m -> handle m)
```

Comment: On the side: You should put the forward pipes *before* the function you pipe into, not *behind* the value you pipe. Lining them up that way makes it much clearer what's going on.

Comment: Each subscription to ab observable pipeline causes a subscription to the source observable. You're creating two subscriptions to the `socket.observable`. You should try putting a publish operator at the end of the `messagesStream` observable.

Comment: Thanks, I found about a publish, do you know any library for f# with publish function? If you can add an answer and code example I will mark that as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add some logging is to use [Observable.iter](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive/blob/455ef947dbfa7d34b2b47f805c85176de830336f/src/FSharp.Control.Reactive/Observable.fs#L955) as follows:

```
let messagesStream = 
  socket.observable
  |> Observable.map (fun () -> socket.read ()) 
  |> Observable.map (fun m -> deserialize m)
  |> Observable.iter (printfn "%A")

messagesStream |> Observable.add (fun m -> handle m)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could create one observable that handles the reading of the message from the network and deserializes it. Assuming this is done with standard Rx operators, that should return an observable that pushes new, deserialized network messages.

You can have 2 subscribers to that observable, one that reacts to new messages with whatever business logic you would like and the second subscriber logging the messages.

That should eliminate the side effect of reading multiple times from the network. Pushing 2 copies of the deserialized message should not incur a side effect.

Comment: I edited the code with an example that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. What you are suggesting is not to use Observable.map but to subscribe to the network and then produce new  observable? can you give a code example?

Comment: Seeing the code you posted, it looks like you tried what I was suggesting in my answer. What exactly is not working?

Comment: take a look at the following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874689/f-observable-filter-with-side-effect

Comment: There are actually two chains created here, which cause the reading and deserializing to happen twice...

Comment: OK. Looks like it. I didn't realize F# operated that way. I've used Rx .NET with C# applications before. I was answering based on my understanding of the way that worked. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Eric - The solution you described doesn't work like that in C# either. Rx queries define a pipeline - which may involve forks - but when you subscribe to an observable you create an instance of the observable all the way to the source. If you have two subscriptions you have two sources.

Comment: @Enigmativity - OK. I can see that. Thanks for clarifying that for me. To achieve only 1 read regardless of the number of subscribers, separate observables would be needed--1 for the network reading and one to manage subscribers & push messages rather than chaining it all to a single observable?

Comment: @Eric - No, you want one observable and publish that to all the subscribers.